# Keras multi-output model

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am using the Keras functional API to build **a model with multiple (five) outputs and the same input**, in order to simultaneously predict different properties of the data (images in my case).

The summary of that model is the following (with capitals are the layers that have been added on top of the pre-trained VGG16) :

[image: model summary]

The shape of the data being fed to the CNN are the following:

```python
# input images
('x_train shape:', (23706, 224, 224, 3))

('Head_1 shape:', (23706, 26))
('Head_2 shape:', (23706,))
('Head_3 shape:', (23706,))
('Head_4 shape:', (23706,))
('Head_5 shape:', (23706,))
```

When I put only a single output to my network the training is carried out without problems, but when all the outputs (or even 2 of them) are present, I am receiving the following error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, train_targets_list, batch_size=batch_size)
.
.
.
.

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (23706,26) into shape (23706)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Also is there any working example in the documentation that describes a similar case for multi-output models?

```python
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='IMAGES')


base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

x = base_model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='GAP')(x)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='FC1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5, name='DROPOUT')(x)


head_1 = Dense(26, activation='sigmoid', name='PREDICTION1') (x)
head_2 = Dense (1, name='PREDICTION2')(x)
head_3 = Dense (1, name='PREDICTION3')(x)
head_4 = Dense (1, name='PREDICTION4')(x)
head_5 = Dense (1, name='PREDICTION5')(x)

outputs_list = [head_1, head_2, head_3, head_4, head_5]


model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=outputs_list)



for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


losses_list = ['binary_crossentropy','mse','mse','mse', 'mse']

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
              loss=losses_list,
              metrics=['accuracy'])


print x_train.shape -> (23706, 224, 224, 3)

for y in train_targets_list:
    print len(y)

23706
23706
23706
23706
23706
```

Comment: post your model code

Comment: Can you print `x_train.shape` and `[print(y.length) for y in train_targets_list]`?

Comment: Can anyone help with that issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333532/load-images-and-annotations-from-csv-and-use-fit-generator-with-multi-output-mod

Comment: Does train_targets_list[0] have a shape of (23706, 26)?  So head_1 is binary classification with 26 different variables, and the other 4 are regression?  Does it work if you only connect head_2 through head_5?