# Load images and annotations from CSV and use fit_generator with multi-output models

Tags: python, keras

Following [issue #10120](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10120), I am using the Keras functional API to build a model with multiple (five) outputs and the same input, in order to simultaneously predict different properties of the data (images in my case). All the metadata of the dataset are stored in different CSV files (one for training, one for validation and one for test data).

[image: aaa.png]

I have already written code to parse the CSV and save all different annotations into different numpy arrays (x_train.npy, emotions.npy etc.) which later I am loading in order to train my CNN.

---

### The issues I want to raise are the following:

**First, what is the most efficient way to save the parsed annotations in order to load them afterwards?**

Is it better to read the annotations on the fly from the CSV file instead of saving them to numpy (or any other format)?

When I load the saved numpy arrays (the following example contains only images and a single metadata)

```
 (x_train, y_train),(x_val, y_val)
```

then I do

```
train_generator = datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32)
```

and finally,

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        epochs=nb_of_epochs,
                        steps_per_epoch= steps_per_epoch,
                        validation_data=val_generator,
                        validation_steps=validation_steps,
                        callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

My program seems to consume up to 20-25GB of RAM for the whole duration of the training process (which is done on GPU). In case I add more than one output my program crashes because of that memory leak (max RAM I've got is 32GB).

**What will be a correct approach for loading the parsed annotations alongside the raw images ?**

Let's say the above issue is fixed, **what will be a correct approach to make use of ImageDataGenerator for multiple outputs** like the following (discussed here as well)

[Keras: How to use fit_generator with multiple outputs of different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972380/keras-how-to-use-fit-generator-with-multiple-outputs-of-different-type)

```
Xi[0], [Yi1[1], Yi2[1],Yi3[1], Yi4[1],Yi5[1]]
```

Comment: If all of your training data does not fit in memory, then you would be better to write a custom generator like the one in the SO question you provided in your question. If you still can't figure how, let me know to elaborate more.

Comment: @today Thanks for that, but I've already written a custom generator similar to the above example (and it seems to work). The main issue is how to read the images alongside their annotations in order to feed them to the generators

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I didn't have time to test it, so it may have bugs or error. Please give me your feedback and any corrections that are necessary to make.

Comment: Thanks for @today
I will test it and let you know.

Comment: Just curious... did it work?

Comment: Sorry for not posting earlier. Yes I managed to achieve what I wanted but not exactly with your answer. The main idea was to generate batches of tensor image data in form of ==> x, [y1, y2, y3, y4, y5]. I will post my working answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def multi_output_generator(hdf5_file, nb_data, batch_size):
    """ Generates batches of tensor image data in form of ==> x, [y1, y2, y3, y4, y5] for use in a multi-output Keras model.

        # Arguments
            hdf5_file: the hdf5 file which contains the images and the annotations.
            nb_data: total number of samples saved in the array.
            batch_size: size of the batch to generate tensor image data for.

        # Returns
            A five-output generator.
    """

    batches_list = list(range(int(ceil(float(nb_data) / batch_size))))

    while True:

        # loop over batches
        for n, i in enumerate(batches_list):
            i_s = i * batch_size  # index of the first image in this batch
            i_e = min([(i + 1) * batch_size, nb_data])  # index of the last image in this batch

            x = hdf5_file["x_train"][i_s:i_e, ...]

            # read labels
            y1 = hdf5_file["y1"][i_s:i_e]
            y2 = hdf5_file["y2"][i_s:i_e]
            y3 = hdf5_file["y3"][i_s:i_e]
            y4 = hdf5_file["y4"][i_s:i_e]
            y5 = hdf5_file["y5"][i_s:i_e]

        yield x, [y1, y2, y3, y4 ,y5]
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that when indexing and slicing a hdf5 file the whole file data is not loaded into memory and only that specific portion is loaded. In this regard, this solution is much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333532/load-images-and-annotations-from-csv-and-use-fit-generator-with-multi-output-mod#comment87685198_50333532), if the whole training data does not fit in memory, you need to write a custom generator (or use the built-in `ImageDataGenerator`, but in your particular scenario it is of no use or at least a bit difficult to make it work).

Here is the custom generator I have written (you need to fill in the necessary parts):

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

def generator(csv_path, batch_size, img_height, img_width, channels, augment=False):

    ########################################################################
    # The code for parsing the CSV (or loading the data files) should goes here
    # We assume there should be two arrays after this:
    #   img_path --> contains the path of images
    #   annotations ---> contains the parsed annotaions
    ########################################################################

    n_samples = len(img_path)
    batch_img = np.zeros((batch_size, img_width, img_height, channels))
    idx = 0
    while True:
        batch_img_path = img_path[idx:idx+batch_size]
        for i, p in zip(range(batch_size), batch_img_path):
            img = image.load_img(p, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
            img = image.img_to_array(img)
            batch_img[i] = img

        if augment:
            ############################################################
            # Here you can feed the batch_img to an instance of 
            # ImageDataGenerator if you would like to augment the images.
            # Note that you need to generate images using that instance as well
            ############################################################

        # Here we assume that the each column in annotations array
        # corresponds to one of the outputs of our neural net
        # i.e. annotations[:,0] to output1, annotations[:,1] to output2, etc. 
        target = annotations[idx:idx+batch_size]
        batch_target = []
        for i in range(annotations.shape[1]):
            batch_target.append(target[:,i])

        idx += batch_size
        if idx > n_samples - batch_size:
            idx = 0

        yield batch_img, batch_target

train_gen = generator(train_csv_path, train_batch_size, 256, 256, 3)
val_gen = generator(val_csv_path, val_batch_size, 256, 256, 3)
test_gen = generator(test_csv_path, test_batch_size, 256, 256, 3)

model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch= , # should be set to num_train_samples / train_batch_size 
                    epochs= , # your desired number of epochs,
                    validation_data= val_gen,
                    validation_steps= # should be set to num_val_samples / val_batch_size)
```

Since I don't know exactly the format and types of the annotations, you may need to make changes to this code to make it work for you. Additionally, considering the current way the `idx` is updated, if `n_sample` is not divisible by `batch_size`, some of the samples at the end may not be used at all. So it can be done much better. One quick fix would be:

```py
idx += batch_size
if idx == n_samples:
    idx = 0
else if idx > n_samples - batch_size:
    idx = n_samples - batch_size
```

However, not matter how you update the `idx`, if you use `fit_generator` and given that `n_samples` is not divisible by `batch_size`, then in each epoch either some of the samples may not be generated or some of the samples may be generated more than once depending on the value of `steps_per_epoch` argument (which I think may not be a significant issue).

Answer (score 0):

Encounter the same problem, at first I managed to write one generator like https://gist.github.com/timehaven/257eef5b0e2d9e2625a9eb812ca2226b, but it can not use multi-process with ease, and latter I found that there is `keras.utils.Sequence()` object (I skipped it because I thought is was `Sequential` model) in keras which is designed just for this purpose, google it or see https://github.com/sdcubber/Keras-Sequence-boilerplate/blob/master/Keras-Sequence.ipynb for one working demo.