# Regression in Keras using images with labels in a csv

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision

I have a dataset of road images and a csv for labels with continuous values (steering angles) that I am trying to predict. The directory looks something like this:

```
  /project1
        /images
              /img1.jpg
              /img2.jpg
              ...
        /labels.csv
```

The labels.csv would look like

```
img   angle

img1   0.018293
img2  -1.265023
...
```

All of my Keras experience is with regard to classification problems where I simply use flow_from_directory on the ImageDataGenerator class

eg.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(...)
```

I realize this isn't possible with regression problems as we can't just put the images in specific folders pertaining to their respective classes.

What would be the most efficient way to create a generator for a regression problem like this? Is there a certain Keras method that I am just not aware of?

Comment: As you said, you need to define a generator. I have sketched a general solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50336100/2099607). You may need to modify it to adapt it to your workflow. If you have saved all the files (i.e. images + labels) in a h5py file, then read the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406642/2099607) to the same question. Currently, sub-classing [Sequence class](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) is more recommended than using a generator specially if you want to do multi-processing; But the code you put in is more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

As `today` already mentioned, you want to sub-class a `Sequence` to provide to `model.fit_generator()`. As it happens, I wrote up a small working example of how to do his with the labels in a .csv file; you can find it [here](https://github.com/sdcubber/Keras-Sequence-boilerplate/blob/master/Keras-Sequence.ipynb).